# Extra iteration of while loop in System Verilog

Tags: while-loop, iteration, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to create a ramped output using a while loop in system verilog and encountering an extra iteration of the loop.

Can anybody please help me understand the reason for this?

```
real a,b,step;
b = #delay final_value;
while (a<b)
  begin
     #delay_per_step a = a + step;
  end
```

(*final_value* is an integral multiple of step)

The final output for ***a*** at the end of this while loop is *final_value + step*

Could this be happening because of the variables being real and exact decimal places not known ?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to rounding errors. You can verify that by displaying the values of `a` and `b` within the loop.

You can subtract a tolerance value to make it work for you

```
while ( a < b - tolerance )
```

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem. I was printing the values for a  & b upto 4 decimal places within the loop, as my step was upto 4 decimal places. And the numbers exactly matched there. Hence couldn't understand the reason for the extra iteration.